# I have lost changes made in my project after wrong git commands

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I'm new to version control, I'm working on a project on VS Code that connected remotely on a Github repository, I was working on some functions, after I finished my changes, I tried to make a commit in my Github repository and push to origin master, but I make a mistake, writing command `git push origin master` without `git add .` and `git commit -m "description"`.

I then realized my mistake and make the commands again like this `git add .`, then  `git commit -m "description"`, then `git push origin master`

It said on terminal `Everything up-to-date`.

So I made `git stash` command thinking it will solve the problem, but it said `No local changes to save`,
and all changes and functions in VS code that I made was lost, back to the state of the last day.

What undo commands can I use to solve my problem.

Comment: None of the commands you listed will remove changes, so there is nothing to do undo.

Comment: Pls edit your post to include the output of `git status`